# Unexpected symbol error when creating a c# array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, unity-game-engine

I have created a class (called Mood) which holds an int, a Vector4 and a float.

I am trying to place three of these objects in an array using the code below:

```
static Vector4 p1 = new Vector4 (0,0,100,0);
static Vector4 p2 = new Vector4 (80,0,0,80);
static Vector4 p3 = new Vector4 (-80,0,0,80);

private Mood[] moods = new Mood[10];

moods[0] = new Mood (1,p1,0.0f);
moods[1] = new Mood (2,p2,0.0f);
moods[2] = new Mood (3,p3,0.0f);
```

However, this gives me the following errors which I don't really understand:

> Invalid rank specifier expected , or ] unexpected symbol new in class, struct or interface member declaration

Could anyone explain what I have done wrong?

the class looks like this

```
public class Mood
{
    public int id = 0;
    public Vector4 pos = null; 
    public float dist = 0.0f;

    public Mood(int inID, Vector4 inPos, float inDist)
    {
        id = inID;
        pos = inPo; 
        dist = inDist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your initialization statements should be in a constructor, basically. You can't have an assignment statement just at the top level of a class declaration.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean? I have a constructor in my class (question edited to include the class)

Comment: @JonSkeet excellent question, can oyu give an example of how the class/classes should be reqritten?

Comment: You've got a constructor in `Mood`, but you haven't told us which class includes the declarations for `p1`, `p2`, `p3` and `moods` - it's the constructor of *that* class that you need to move the initialization into.

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by a pretty silly mistake. If you're using classes you need to declare/define them in the script before you try to use them. In this case I placed my classes at the bottom of the script, so the constructor in the main class didn't have a definition.